# Sql Server (breaking sting and doing operations in that order)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have varchar value of @Order as 'ST,OT,DT' OR 'OT,ST,DT'  and so on with all possible combinations of ST,OT,DT .

Then I want to implement logic in stored procedure as below for @order = 'ST,OT,DT'
if ST comes first then deduct from @SThours,
If @SThours is zero , decuct from @OThours,
if @OThours is zero, deduct from @DThours

I could go on and write if else condition for all possible combinations .. but wanted to have nice implementation so that in future if new value comes I dont need to change my code......

Comment: If the string is always in that format, then you can easily use SUBSTRING to extract the values and of course you will know their order at that point. After that, you can implement whatever logic you need; it isn't clear what you mean by a "nice implementation" or how you expect to make this more general/flexible?

Comment: Basically I dont want to write too many if else statments... But implementation something like 
If @firstvalue is ST 
then deduct from '@firstvalue' + Hours    
else if '@firstvalue' + Hours     is zero then deduct from '@secondvalue' + Hours   and so on
This will avoid too many if else and clean code....

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with using IF, but depending on your logic you may be able to write it using CASE instead. But CASE cannot do control-of-flow and it can only return one value, so not all logic can be expressed that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something you could do:

```
declare @valueToDeductFrom int, @currentIndex int, @currentFieldName char(2)

set @valueToDeductFrom = 0
set @currentIndex = 1

while @currentIndex < 8 and @valueToDeductFrom = 0
begin
    set @currentFieldName = substring(@order, @currentIndex, 2)

    set @valueToDeductFrom = 
        case 
            when @currentFieldName = 'ST' then @SThours
            when @currentFieldName = 'OT' then @OThours
            when @currentFieldName = 'DT' then @DThours
            else 0
        end

    set @currentIndex = @currentIndex + 3
end

-- do something with @valueToDeductFrom here... Probably deduct from it. :)
```

Comment: yes  w0lf. something like only..  thanks for your help ... :)